# The square of each t-statistics is the corresponding F-statistics

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, f-statistic

The below text is from [statistical learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) Page 76-77. The data used in the following example can be found [here](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv) .
I just want to know

how to calculate $RSS_0$   (It is different from TSS)

As listed in the point 1 below **the square of each t-statistics is the corresponding F-statistics** please explain this point. (What I understand from this is that in a simple linear model with one variable the square of t-statistics of a variable is equal to it's F-statistics. Am I correct ? My other question is, Is this also valid for multiple regression models  as I found if I do the sum of squares of all values of t-statistics in the figure below (except intercept ) is not equal to F-statistics? Please clarify what the authors want to convey here)

> Sometimes we want to test that a particular subset of q of the
>   coeﬃcients are zero. This corresponds to a null hypothesis  $H_0 :
> > β_{p−q+1} = β_{p−q+2} = ...= β_p =0$
>
> where for convenience we have put the variables chosen for omission at
>   the end of the list. In this case we ﬁt a second model that uses all
>   the variables except those last q. Suppose that the residual sum of
>   squares for that model is $RSS_0$. Then the appropriate F-statistic is
>   $$F=\frac{(RSS_0-RSS)/q}{RSS/(n-p-1)}$$

[image]

> Notice that in the table above, for each individual predictor a
>   t-statistic and a p-value were reported. These provide information
>   about whether each individual predictor is related to the response,
>   after adjusting for the other predictors. It turns out that each of
>   these are exactly $equivalent^1$ to the F-test that omits that single
>   variable from the model, leaving all the others in—i.e. q=1 in
>   $$F=\frac{(RSS_0-RSS)/q}{RSS/(n-p-1)}$$
>
> So it reports the partial eﬀect of adding that variable to the model.
>
> **1.The square of each t-statistic is the corresponding F-statistic**

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is correct.  You can interchange the t and F statistics as from a theoretical point of view the F distribution arises for the square of a random variable with a t distribution. Similarly the square of a normal random variable has a $\chi^2$ distribution, so you can expect the square of a z statistic to be $\chi^2$ distributed. What the author wants to convey in that table is that if you took the t statistic value and squared it, it would be exactly equal to the F statistic as calculated from the given formula.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The square of t-statistic equal to partial F-test.